# Find $f_1$, $f_2$ such that $f_1$ has critical points but $f_2\circ f_1$ does not

Tags: calculus, functions, examples-counterexamples

I want two smooth functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that $f_1$ has critical points but $f_2\circ f_1$ does not.

At first I considered $f_1:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ to be $f_1(x,y)=xy$, and tried to find $f_2:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_2 \circ f_1(x,y)=f_2 (xy)$ would be something with constant derivative but I couldn’t get any thing.

Then I tried to assume that $f_2 \circ f_1(x,y)=x+y$ and then trying to go backward to find $f_1$ and $f_2$ but no results too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A critical point of $f_1$ is also a critical point of $f_2 \circ f_1$, as the chain rule shows (assuming that both functions are differentiable).

Comment: There are certainly examples, even for functions of one variable; @MartinR's comment reveals that at least one of the functions can't be differentiable everywhere. Hint: what if you try to make $f_2\circ f_1(x)=x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both differentiable functions, it is not possible beucase of the chain rule $(f_2 \circ f_1)' (x) = (f_2' \circ f_1(x)) f_1'(x)$. So if $f_1'(x)=0$ we have $(f_2 \circ f_1)' (x)=0$.

If we allow $f_2$ to be not differentiable, here is a hint to find an example in one variable. Consider $f_1(x)=x^2 sign(x)$, which has a critical point at $x=0$. Can you find $f_2$ such that $f_2 \circ f_1 = Id$ ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that they are smooth. My bad.

Comment: Then this answer sketches the argument that such a composition does not exist.

Comment: You’re right I can see that now. Thank you! I edited my post.